# How do I loop through nested structs using Jinja in DBT?

Tags: python, sql, jinja2, dbt

I'm trying to build a model in DBT that flattens out a struct with name `properties` that contains about a hundred structs inside it (e.g. `property1`, `property2`, etc.), each with 5 different columns of which I want to extract one called `value`. I could type `properties.propertyX.value` 100 times, but I figured I could try to find a way to loop through each struct within `properties` and obtain `propertyX.value` within a `SELECT` statement by using Jinja, but I guess I'm either unfamiliar with the syntax or its limitations because I don't know what to do. I've tried:

```
WITH t as (
    SELECT
        properties
    FROM
        src
)
SELECT
    {% for property in properties %}
    {{property}}.value
    {% endfor %}
    {%- if not loop.last %},{% endif -%}
FROM
    t
```

but I realized I have to set `properties` as a variable and I don't really know how to do that in a way that it references the individual properties in the `properties` struct. Anyway, I'm quite lost and if someone could help I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if I followed 100% your data structure, but let's say it's similar to this:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "property1": {
      "column1": "...",
      "column2": "...",
      "column3": "...",
      "value": "my value 1.0"
    },
    "property2": {
      "column1": "...",
      "column2": "...",
      "column3": "...",
      "value": "my value 2.0"
    },
    "propertyX": {
      "column1": "...",
      "column2": "...",
      "column3": "...",
      "value": "my value 3.0"
    }
  }
}
```

As you mention, you need to use `set` to create variables and to be able to manipulate your data. Personally, I like to create different variables to handle the `query statement`, the `query result`, and the `query values`. So following this strategy you would have something like this:

```sql
{% set data_structure_query %}
    select properties from src
{% endset %}

{% set results = run_query(data_structure_query) %}

{% set properties = results.columns[0].values() %}
```

> Note that `results.columns[0].values()` will bring the data of the first column of your query which in this case it's the `properties`.

The `.values()` get the values of the column as a tuple, where the items most of the time is defined as a `string`. So in order to access the properties of your data, you will have to deserialize the json string into a Python object, e.g. `dict`. To do that, you need to use the `fromjson` method:

```sql
...

{% set properties = results.columns[0].values() %}

{% set properties_dict = fromjson(properties[0]) %}

...
```

> Assuming your query return only one row with the JSON format, I specified the `properties[0]` to access the first row of the result query.

Before jumping to the next step, it's important to know that dbt has a jinja variable that informs us when dbt is in the "execute mode". That's a thing we need to worry about since it can raise issues to build our models. In short, any jinja that relies on a result being returned from the database will throw an error.

In your case, the `results` variable is depending on a value that needs to be executed in the database which means if you just try to run the model most likely you'll get an issue with `Compilation Error`. To avoid that, you need to add an `if condition` to check if dbt is in "execute mode" or not:

```sql
...

{% set results = run_query(data_structure_query) %}

{% if execute %}
    {% set properties = results.columns[0].values() %}
    {% set properties_dict = fromjson(properties[0]) %}
{% else %}
    {% set properties = [] %}
    {% set properties_dict = [] %}
{% endif %}

...
```

Finally, you can proceed with a `loop` to build your columns:

```sql
select
{%- for property in properties_dict.properties %}
    {{ property }}.value
    {%- if not loop.last %},{% endif -%}
{%- endfor %}
from 
...
```

This will be compiled to:

```sql
select
    property1.value,
    property2.value,
    propertyX.value
from
...
```

If you want to access the values for each column, then:

```sql
select
{%- for property in properties_dict.properties %}
    '{{ properties_dict.properties[property].value }}'
    {%- if not loop.last %},{% endif -%}
{%- endfor %}
from
...
```

Which will be compiled to:

```sql
select
    'my value',
    'my value 1.0',
    'my value 2.0'
from
...
```

Might be worth taking a look in your database/warehouse and check if there is any internal function that handles semi-structured data. This can help you with the logic too. For instance, Snowflake has the `lateral flatten` that does a similar behavior to split the properties into multiple rows.

For debug purposes, I recommend to `compile` your model and use the logs (`{{ log('my message', info=True) }}`) to understand how dbt/jinja is processing the data. Some of the code I provided might change depending on the output of your query.

#### Some helpful links:

https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query

https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/execute

https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/fromjson/

https://docs.getdbt.com/tutorial/using-jinja

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data structure looks like this:

```
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "value": "Value 1"
    },
    {
      "value": "Value 2"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

You just need to move the .value lookup into the variable delimiters: `{{ property.value }}`